# Multiple Laravel bootable traits not working

Tags: php, laravel

Using multiple boot traits with the same event will fire just the first one and ignore the rest bootable traits.

```php
class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasKey; // this will work (but if i put it bellow it will not work)
    use HasSlug; // this's not (but if i put it above it will work)
}
```

```php
trait HasKey
{
    public static function bootHasKey()
    {
        static::creating(
            fn (Model $model) => $model->key = 'value'
        );
    }
```

```php
trait HasSlug
{
    public static function bootHasSlug()
    {
        static::creating(
            fn (Model $model) => $model->slug = 'value'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Use commas - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.multiple

Comment: This is just a convention!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? First thing I would do is some logging in each boot method to make sure they're being called, same for the event handling methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's not supported at the moment, maybe in the future releases of Laravel!

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/40645#issuecomment-1022969116

Comment: Just a note that that thread indicates this was fixed in Laravel 8.

Comment: @ceejayoz that's referring to [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32159) so the other answer is potentially a solution, but it needs to explain itself better.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use closure instead of arrow function like this:

```php
trait HasKey
{
    public static function bootHasKey()
    {
        static::creating(
            function (Model $model) { $model->key = 'value'; }
        );
    }
}
```

```php
trait HasSlug
{
    public static function bootHasSlug()
    {
        static::creating(
            function (Model $model) { $model->slug = 'value'; }
        );
    }
}
```

Because arrow functions always return a value, so laravel will stop the event propagation after the first event handler is executed.

[You can see the source code here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9b025125c611e99aaab79c42e5a82ac2a7ed8a50/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php#L188)

Comment: This answer provides aboslutely no context or explanation, which is probably why it got a downvote. In 99% of cases arrow functions and regular functions are interchangeable, so [edit] your answer to explain *why* making the change will resolve the problem in the question. What is the difference between the two syntaxes in the context of an Eloquent event method?